# Register unique callbacks per instance using classmethod

Tags: python, python-2.7, decorator, class-method

I wanted to make it easier to register callbacks using decorators when designing a library, but the problem is that they both use the same instance of the Consumer.

I am trying to allow both these examples to co-exist in the same project.

```
class SimpleConsumer(Consumer):
     @Consumer.register_callback
     def callback(self, body)
         print body

class AdvancedConsumer(Consumer):
     @Consumer.register_callback
     def callback(self, body)
         print body

a = AdvancedConsumer()
s = SimpleConsumer()
```

What happens here is that the callback implementation of AdvancedConsumer will override the one of the SimpleConsumer, as it is defined last.

The implementation of the decorator class is pretty simple.

```
class Consumer(object):
      def start_consumer(self):
            self.consuming_messages(callback=self._callback)

       @classmethod
       def register_callback(cls, function):        
           def callback_function(cls, body):
               function(cls, body)

           cls._callback = callback_function
           return callback_function
```

I am very happy with the implementation, but as there is a possibility that someone will register a second callback I would like to ensure that it won't be a problem in the future. So, does anyone have a suggestion on how to implement this in a way that is not static?

The implementation shown here is obviously simplified, and as a precaution I have something like this in the code.

```
if cls._callback:
    raise RuntimeError('_callback method already defined')
```

Comment: If there can be only one callback function, why not just call it `_callback` in the child class and never mess with the registration? Is there something else that has to be done?

Comment: There are additional steps in the decorator not mentioned in the example above, and the idea is that I want the class inheriting the Consumer class to be as simple as possible. Preferably I just want the callback and set up to be handled there (e.g. hostname, username, pw).

A decorator was for me the cleanest way to implement this.

Comment: If there are additional steps then it probably depends on them what is the best method here. For me the simplest solution is just always call the callback `_callback`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with a class decorator:

```
def register_callback(name):
    def decorator(cls):
        cls._callback = getattr(cls, name)
        return cls
    return decorator

@register_callback('my_func')
class SimpleConsumer(Consumer):
     def my_func(self, body):
         print body
```

If you want to decorate a method, you will get only a function in it so you cannot access any information about the class that the method is contained in.

But if only one callback should be available per class why just not call it `_callback`?

```
class SimpleConsumer(Consumer):
     def _callback(self, body):
         print body
```

Or do something like:

```
class SimpleConsumer(Consumer):
     def my_func(self, body):
         print body

     _callback = my_func
```

?

Comment: It didn't even cross my mind, but getting `NameError: name 'SimpleConsumer' is not defined`.

Comment: Ah sorry my mistake, I'll fix it in a sec :)

Comment: No worries. It's such a stupid problem, that I did not take into account when designing this so I am happy with even the tiniest nudge in the right direction. =D

Comment: Thanks, that does indeed work. I handle a couple of other-things in the background, like if and how to acknowledge messages has been processed, but I'll see if I can come up with a good solution around this.

Comment: If you need a reference to the `Consumer` class then you can always make the `register_callback` a classmethod of the `Consumer` class and call it with `@Consumer.register_callback('my_func')`